# Excel VBA: Copy data from cell above in blank cells, but only in columns A-B

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 columns of data. The data is grouped by employee name and number (cols A-B) and their respective pay types (col C). I need to

1. Copy employee name to blank cell below in col A
2. Copy employee number to blank cell below in col B
3. Add the word "Advance" in the blank cell in col C

Current code selects all blank cells in cols A-E and fills with the values from above:

```vb
Sub FillBlanksValueAbove1()
Dim sName As String
sName = ActiveSheet.Name
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range

'Set variable ws Active Sheet name
Set ws = Sheets(sName)

    With ws
    'Get the last row and last column
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Set the range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    rng.Select
    'Select Blanks
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    'Fill Blanks with value above
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    'Paste Formulas as Values
    rng.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End With
End Sub
```

This is what the spreadsheet looks like now:
[image: Current Spreadsheet]

This is what I need it to look like:
[image: Desired End Result]

This is the end result I currently get:
[image: Current, Incorrect End Result]

Thank you so so much!

Comment: And which is your problem?

Comment: The problem is the end result I currently get (image #3). As you can see, the pay type (col C) Pay Units (col D) and Pay Rate (col E) populate. I don't want them to populate. They need to be left blank.

Comment: Then, try the my answer code...

Answer (score 0):

Test the next code, please. No need of any selection, a little simplified:

```
Sub FillBlanksValueAbove1()
 Dim rng As Range, rngVis As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

 'Set variable ws Active Sheet name
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 With ws
    'Get the last row
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Set the range
    Set rng = .Range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(lastRow, 2)) 'Col B:C
 
    Set rngVis = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    'Fill ADVANCE in column C:C
    rngVis.Offset(, 1).Value = "ADVANCE"
    'Fill Blanks with value above
    rngVis.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    
    'Paste Formulas as Values
     rngVis.Value = rngVis.Value
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @colette: Before copying the above code, please refresh the page (this one). I adapted the code, simplifying it...

Comment: Thanks! It's almost correct. For some reason the very last portion ('Paste Formulas as Values) doesn't work quite right. I changed that last portion to the following:

'Paste Formulas as Values
    Sheets("Final-Employees").Range("A:E").Copy
    Sheets("Final-Employees").Range("A:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Other than that it works like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: You do not use the last version. This line 'rngVis.Value = rngVis.Value' does the job instead of PasteSpecial. Now I closed my laptop and use my phone. If something not workung as you need, please specify. I will solve it tomorrow...

Comment: @colette: Do you still have a problem using the above code?